# Kendo - Angular dropdown closing on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui-angular2

Hi I am working on Kendo and I am using https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/

Whenever we will search something and try to scroll, drop-down closes automatically. It is not happening all the time but once it happens I need to reload the browser then again it will work.

The exact same issue, I found for material UI can be check for more understanding https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/901

How I can resolve the issue? Any help will be useful ...

Thanks

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/forums/prevent-popup-close-on-scrolling

Comment: Cannot help you without looking at the code.